# Tkcalendar configure DateEntry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

Is there any way to configure the DateEntry widget itself as you would with a normal entry widget (not the drop down calendar)? For example change the font, relief or background etc...

I've tried the following:

```
myDateEntry.config(background='red')
```

but i just get:

*AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute 'background'*

When i define the DateEntry widget i can do the following:

```
myDateEntry=DateEntry(root,background='red')
```

which doesn't cause an error, but only changes the background of the drop down calendar.

Comment: Which version of tkcalendar are you using? I am not getting any error with `myDateEntry.config(background='red')`, it just does the same as `myDateEntry=DateEntry(root,background='red')` which is the expected behavior (I am tkcalendar's developper)

Comment: Seems to work as you described now, not sure what was happening before. I probably made some typo somewhere, but i definitely got the error, because i copied it in. `tkcalendar==1.5.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DateEntry` widget is based on a `ttk.Entry`, not  a `tk.Entry`, so you have to use a style to change its appearance. This is explained in the documentation: https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howtos.html#widget-styling

Like for a `ttk.Entry`, if you want a red background, you need to set the `fieldbackground` option of the style to 'red', except that the style to change is 'DateEntry' instead of 'TEntry':

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
# create custom DateEntry style with red background
style.configure('my.DateEntry', fieldbackground='red')
# create DateEntry using the custom style
dateentry = DateEntry(root, style='my.DateEntry') 
dateentry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Note:** Not all ttk themes allow to change the `fieldbackground` of the widgets, especially Windows default theme. To be able to change it therefore the theme needs to be changed first with `style.theme_use('clam')` to use, for instance, the 'clam' theme.

Comment: Ok, thanks I understand I've got to use ttk's styles now. I can't seem to get `fieldbackground` working though, it doesn't seem to change anything. I've tested other things like `foreground` which work fine. If it makes any difference, I'm changing the style later on, like so: `dateentry['style']='my.DateEntry'

Comment: Try changing theme, some do not support all options, especially Windows and Mac default themes: e.g. with `style.theme_use('clam')` you should be able to change the fieldbackground.